# I was trying to make discord bot that kick user and its not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

Main Code:

```js
const Discord = require("discord.js");

const client = new Discord.Client();

const prefix = ";";

client.once("ready", () => {
    console.log("Online dziecino!");
    client.user.setActivity("jebanie bydgoszczy", {
        type: "STREAMING",
        url: "https://www.twitch.tv/its_not_important",
    });
});

client.on("message", (message) => {
    if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;

    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/);
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

    if (command === "kick") {
        client.commands.get("kick").execute(message, args);
    }
});

client.login("my token is here");
```

Kick Command:

```js
module.exports = {
    name: "kick",
    description: "This command kicks a member!",
    execute(message, args) {
        const target = message.mentions.users.first();
        if (target) {
            const memberTarget = message.guild.members.cache.get(target.id);
            memberTarget.kick();
            message.channel.send("User has been kicked");
        } else {
            message.channel.send('You coudn\'t kick that member!');
        }
    },
};
```

Error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined
    at Client.<anonymous> (C:\Users\kubak\Desktop\Discord Bot\main.js:82:18)
    at Client.emit (events.js:315:20)
```

Comment: You haven't even used a command handler. Then how do you think your code is supposed to work? See [command handler](https://discordjs.guide/command-handling/)

Answer (score 1):

You need command handler:

Add this to your code:

```
client.commands= new Discord.Collection();
const commandFiles = readdirSync(join(__dirname, "commands")).filter(file => file.endsWith(".js"));
for (const file of commandFiles) {
const command = require(join(__dirname, "commands", `${file}`));
client.commands.set(command.name, command);
}
```

And add this before the "Token" :

```
client.on("message", async message => {

  if(message.author.bot) return;
  if(message.channel.type === 'dm') return;


  if(message.content.startsWith(prefix)) {
      const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/);

      const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

      if(!client.commands.has(command)) return;


      try {
          client.commands.get(command).run(client, message, args);

      } catch (error){
          console.error(error);
      }
  }
})
```

Add a folder with the name "commands" to your bot's directory.
Put kick command in commands folder.

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');



module.exports = {
    name: "kick",
    description: "This command kicks a member!",

    async run (client, message, args) {

        const target = message.mentions.members.first() || message.guild.members.cache.get(args[0]);
         
        if(!args[0]) return message.channel.send('Error, write target');


        target.kick(reason)
        .catch(err => {
            if(err) return message.channel.send('Error.')
        })


    }
}
```